# Node.js setInterval stops running after a while

Tags: node.js

I've noticed that some of my programs that use setInterval and that run over long periods of time eventually stop running. I usually run these programs through window's cmd. The instance I notice that a program stops running and I press ctrl+c, it starts running again. I've changed the power settings of my computer to never sleep or shut off its display, but my programs still eventually stops.

I'm not sure what's causing the program to stop running over long periods of time.

Comment: as you know setTimeout will stop eventually when the time you set finished

Comment: Sorry, I meant setInterval!

Comment: I got the same issue like you but mine is the influxDB service. I noticed that when you clicked on the window's cmd on blank area, It will stop execute the service (in my situation is stopping my influxDB service). And when I press ctl+C it resume, like you. So I think you should not click on cmd when the programe is running.

Comment: Usually the reason that a nodejs program stops running after awhile is that your program is leaking some type of resource (memory, file handle, database connection, socket, etc...) that starts causing internal errors at some point and the only way around it is to restart the process and let the OS reclaim the leaked resources.